# After fetching data from MySQL database fetching column data from nth row and assigning to variable

Tags: php, mysql

So I have fetched data from a MySQL database and I want to assign it to a variable based on an nth row. Only the bottom three rows are filtered and I want to assign values from the firs and last row to two variables.

```
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM login_attempts WHERE login_attempt_user_id=? AND login_attempt_result=? ORDER BY login_attempt_id DESC LIMIT 3;";
$stmt3 = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt3, $sql3)) {
    echo 6;
    exit();

} else {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt3, "ss", $login_attempt_user_id, $login_attempt_success);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt3);
    $result2 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt3);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) {

        while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {

            $test1 = $row2['login_attempt_time'][0];

            $test2 = $row2['login_attempt_time'][2];

            echo $test1.$test2;
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        //echo 4;
        exit();
    }
}
```

The section of code is within the while loop and I realize that what I am attempting is for arrays. I want to do something similar to achieve my goal.

My code is not assigning the database entry to the variable: `$test = $row2['login_attempt_time']` assigns the last value of the fetched row, however `$test = $row2['login_attempt_time'][0]` only returns the value `1`.

Would anyone please be able to help with this?

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel please see my updated question, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: So from three rows in the result you want to get the first and the last? And throw away the middle (second) one?

Comment: Not necessarily discard the middle... I just want the value of the first row to be assigned to `$variable1` and the last row to `$variable2`, for example. So when I call `$variable1` it will echo that specific value from the database and a different value for `$variable2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch all (three) rows into an array (2-dimensional) with [`mysqli::fetch_all()`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php). Then get the first and the last elements (rows) with [`reset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) and [`end()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php).

Change

```
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {

        $test1 = $row2['login_attempt_time'][0];

        $test2 = $row2['login_attempt_time'][2];

        echo $test1.$test2;
        exit();
    }
```

to

```
    $data = $result2->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $variable1 = reset($data); // first row
    $variable2 = end($data);   // last row
```

Comment: Ok so I see I have to fetch the specified data by `$final_result = $variable1['login_attempt_time'];` Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Remember, this `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))` will fetch one row from the database. So the first time, `$row2` will be the contents of the first row, the second time `$row2` is the second row, etc. Perhaps add a counter to the loop to know when to populate $test1 and $test2, as with an `if` condition.